# How can I detect if I already delete a multiline inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Autogrow TextArea. Height is adjusting once I pressed enter key. What I want is to reduce the height if I deleted a line in the multiline of the textarea. This is my current code:

```js
$('.autogrow').each(function () {
    h(this);
}).on('keypress', function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
        h(this);
    }
});

function h(e) {
    $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="invite_email" id="invite_email" value="" class="autogrow" placeholder="Email Address" style="resize:none;overflow:hidden;-ms-overflow-style: none;min-height: 44px;border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;height: 44px; background: #fff;border-radius: 4px;    padding: 6px 12px !important;font-size: 14px !important; line-height: 2; width: 100%; margin: 0;"></textarea>
```

Comment: What happens if a single line without line break is longer than your textarea and spills into the next line without line break? How do you calculate the size then? I feel listening to `enter` is not very effective here?

Comment: @Dominik once your pressed enter in a textarea there's a "\n" that generate. In my functions I'm exploding the content of the textarea. $lines = explode("\n", $invite_email);

Comment: Why not use an input instead of textarea if you don't ask for multiple emails?

Comment: @Benjoe then run this function everytime something changes `onChange` ...?

Comment: @KK, this feature is a bulk email invitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function to resize only on enter key press.

```
if(e.which == 13){
    h(this);
}
```

Remove that and call the function to resize on each keypress

```js
$('.autogrow').each(function () {
    h(this);
}).on('keyup', function (e) {
    h(this);
  
});

function h(e) {
    $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="invite_email" id="invite_email" value="" class="autogrow" placeholder="Email Address" style="resize:none;overflow:hidden;-ms-overflow-style: none;min-height: 44px;border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;height: 44px; background: #fff;border-radius: 4px;    padding: 6px 12px !important;font-size: 14px !important; line-height: 2; width: 100%; margin: 0;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Didn't notice  that. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 4):

Try to play with number of rows:

```js
var ROW_HEIGHT = 13;

function resize_(e) {
  var rows = txt.value.split(/\n/).length;
  txt.style.height = rows * ROW_HEIGHT + 'px';
}

var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
txt.addEventListener('paste', resize_);
txt.addEventListener('input', resize_);
txt.addEventListener('change', resize_);
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">row 1
row 2</textarea>
```